# Can StoreDot batteries be charged in two minutes?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, mobile-phones

CNET [writes](http://www.cnet.com/news/storedot-rapid-charging-battery-heads-to-smartphones-this-year/):

> StoreDot's system, which you can see in action in the video [at the link], uses a different chemical makeup to traditional batteries. We saw a modified Samsung Galaxy S5 go from 15 percent battery to 100 percent in a little under two minutes, but StoreDot says it hopes to get a 1,500mAh battery to charge in one minute by the end of the year.

Is this legit? Has StoreDot really developed batteries that can be charged in 2 minutes? What about the claims about super capacitors on their website?

Comment: I fixed your question so the claim is consistent with the article: 2 minutes, not 30 seconds; they use special custom batteries, not generic lithium ones.